# Throughput calculation using response time and no of request

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

I received an requirement were I need to display the response time, number of threads running, latency and throughput in one report. I used below code in Beanshell post processor to display throughput, response time and number of threads:

```java
long repons=prev.getTime();
vars.put("responseTime",String.valueOf(recons));
//print("res" +responseTime);
log.info("Response time" + repons);
long thread=prev.getAllThreads();

vars.put("threads", Integer.toString(prev.getAllThreads()));
log.info("Thread number is"+thread);
float throughput=thread/repons;
log.info("Through put"+throughput);
```

I guess it is wrong. Can anyone help on this?

Answer (score 0):

1. You have syntax error in your script, you have `repons` in the first line and `recons` in the second, they should be the same
2. It is better to use [JSR223 Elements](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) and [Groovy language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) for scripting.
3. And finally, your approach is wrong, according to [JMeter glossary](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/glossary.html):

   > **Throughput** is calculated as requests/unit of time. The time is calculated from the start of the first sample to the end of the last sample. This includes any intervals between samples, as it is supposed to represent the load on the server.
   >
   > The formula is: **Throughput = (number of requests) / (total time)**.

   So you need to divide **total number** of requests by **total time** taken to 
   execute these requests, your "code" most likely will be returning zero throughput

You can consider the following workarounds:

- Use [Backend Listener](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Backend_Listener) and a 3rd-party visualisation tool, see [Real-time results](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/realtime-results.html) article for details.
- Run your JMeter test via [Taurus](http://gettaurus.org/) framework which has [Interactive Reporting](http://gettaurus.org/docs/Reporting/) feature

Comment: Can throughput be displayed in .jtl result file ?

Comment: You can **calculate** it basing on the data from the .jtl result file. Or just open .jtl results file with i.e. [Aggregate Report](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Aggregate_Report) listener which will do the necessary calculation. Or upload .jtl results file to a 3rd-party analysis service like [BM.Sense](https://sense.blazemeter.com/). Or elaborate your requirements so we could come up with more suggestions.

Comment: The Requirement is,Want to display Throughput,Latency and response time in a single report.Should see the capacity of the application for how many threads application can handle what is breakpoint of application.